# GitHub Template with Updates - How? I thought Forks are the solution but they are not

Tags: git, github, templates, fork, updates

I have repos like:

https://github.com/iOSonntag-templates/SOME_TEMPLATE

and want others (including myself) to get a copy of the template.

So far so good.

What I also want is that when I make changes to the template, that all depending projects have the ability to get the latest changes merged into their own clone/fork/repo/"fill in the blanks".

A perfect fit for "Just Fork The Repo" I thought. But it turns out that GitHub only allows forking a repo just once (why I do not know).

So If I forked:

https://github.com/iOSonntag-templates/flutter-app

into:

https://github.com/iOSonntag/flutter-iospot

I am not allowed to fork another copy into:

https://github.com/iOSonntag/web-iosonntag

Is there another way to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish?